# If sulfur is directly below oxygen on the periodic table, why isn't SO the most common sulfur oxide? Instead of third, behind SO2 and SO3?

Tags: stoichiometry, molecules, covalent-compounds, periodic-table

Chalcogen like oxygen and sulfur want to 'grab' (or share) two electrons to get to eight, if possible, or maybe 'give up' (or share) six, if necessary, to again get to eight... Right?

So, why is sulfur dioxide, where the sulfur shares four electrons (usually), more common than sulfur monoxide or sulfur trioxide?

Isn't sulfur dioxide a higher energy, less stable molecule?

Comment: Main group elements, from orders higher then 2nd, really don't like double bonds. Another thing is that sulfur oxidises easily. BTW I don't think I can say I like questions of "Why chemistry is as it is?" type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do sulfur and oxygen form sulfur dioxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/why-do-sulfur-and-oxygen-form-sulfur-dioxide)

Comment: Sulfur monoxide is unstable and has been rarely observed in stable conditions. It has been detected in space however. Normally, it is prepared by decomposing ethylene episulfoxide but it is so unstable that it quickly dimerizes to disulfur dioxide which is also unstable and converts to stable sulfur oxides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody really knows why $\ce{SO}$ is such a rare and unstable substance. It is an orange gas at room temperature. The only way to synthesize $\ce{SO}$ is to reduce thionyl chloride $\ce{SOCl2}$ with some reagent eager to react with the chlorine atom, like sodium, silver or tin : $$\ce{SOCl2 + 2 Na -> SO + 2 NaCl}$$ The strangest property of this gas is its reaction with water. It is decomposed with the smallest amount of water vapor according to the disproportion equation : $$\ce{3SO + H2O -> H2S + 2 SO2}$$ It is an extraordinary reaction, as it requires $3$ molecules $\ce{SO}$. Another oxide is known to disproportionate with water : $\ce{NO2}$. But there is a good reason for this behavior : $\ce{NO2}$ has an uneven number of electrons. It is not the case for $\ce{SO}$.

Comment: It looks like water must be present in stoichiometric amounts for complete disproportionation. The orange color in a gas raises suspicions that it might be reactive in a redox fashion there are some loosely held electrons somewhere.